# Windows partition not shown in Ubuntu live session

Tags: windows, live-usb, ntfs

Recently my laptop running Windows 7 crashed and I am trying to back up the data before trying any recovery. For this I booted Ubuntu ubuntu-10.10-desktop-i386 (USB booted not installed on my HDD) and tried to mount the Win7 partitions to copy the files, But I could not see the all partitions in Ubuntu.

My partitions are:

- C: 310 GB
- D: 200MB (System Recovery)
- E:100GB
- F:100GB
- G:130GB

only C & D are mounted, all other drives are not mounted and also not listed in `fdisk -l`. If I run the Disk Utility the I could see the 310GB(C) & 200MB(D) as NTFS, where as the there is 340GB Free as Unallocated Space.

Please help me to detect and mount all the Win7 partition in Ubuntu.

Comment: There are 5 partitions, so they can't all be primary.
How have your formated the last 3 partitions? What does a `sudo parted /dev/sda print` say?

Comment: The laptop came with 2 partition C(windos installation) & D (Sys recovery), I shrink the C partion and made the other partions, I remember the new partitions are extented logical partions. Let me try the parted /dev/sda and give you the print

Comment: I used a utility "Test Disk" from AVG and that could able to see all the partitions and I recovered all the data. Finally I formatted to factory settings. seems there was a corrupt on partition table.

Answer (score 1):

I used a utility "Test Disk" from AVG (Free, DOS based) and that was able to see all the partitions and I recovered all the data (copied to another USB medium).

Seems there was a corrupted partition table. I formatted the hard drive to factory settings using my laptop's factory image restore dicks.